# Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 2 in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, collation

The following SQL statement is giving me a "Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 2 in SELECT statement." error.

I can tell the culprit is `RTRIM(TABLE_ONE.AUT_NAME)` because the statement works if I remove it. However, if I use COLLATE before it I get a syntax error. How can I resolve this issue? thanks

```
SELECT NRS, RTRIM(STR_DES) + ', ' + RTRIM(TABLE_TWO.TO_NA) 
        AS FT_NAME, KEYWORDS = CAST(NRS AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + RTRIM(STR_DES) + '' + 
        RTrim(TABLE_THREE.LC_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(TABLE_TWO.TO_NA) + '' + 
        RTRIM(TABLE_ONE.AUT_NAME) 
        From NSG_STR INNER Join TABLE_TWO On TABLE_TWO.TN_UID = NSG_STR.TN_UID INNER Join 
        TABLE_THREE ON TABLE_THREE.LCT_UID = NSG_STR.LCT_UID INNER JOIN TABLE_ONE ON TABLE_ONE.AUT_UID = NSG_STR.AUT_UID 
        WHERE CAST(NRS As VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + RTRIM(STR_DES) + ' ' + RTRIM(TABLE_THREE.LC_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(TABLE_TWO.TO_NA) + '' + 
        RTrim(TABLE_ONE.AUT_NAME) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '%3%'
```

Comment: Have a look at the column definition for `NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME` to see what the collation is.  It must differ from the columns before it, which is why you are seeing this error

Comment: You need to change the collation of `NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME` in the query, and to do this you can do `RTRIM(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME COLLATE XXXXX)`, replacing `XXXXX` with the collation of the other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this before your code:

```
declare @db_collation nvarchar(100) = (select cast( databasepropertyex(db_name(),'collation') as nvarchar) )
declare @altertablequery nvarchar(500)
set @altertablequery = '
alter table NSG_AUTHORITY alter column AUTHORITY_NAME nvarchar (max) collate '+@db_collation+';'
exec (@altertablequery)
```

Comment: For future visitors to this accepted answer: This code will **permanently** change the collation of the column.  This may not be the right solution for all scenarios as the different collation may have been explicitly chosen for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is to simply add "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" to your query, which requires no schema modifications at all.

```
SELECT USRN, RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + ', ' + RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) 
        AS FEATURE_NAME, KEYWORDS = CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + '' + 
        RTrim(NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) + '' + 
        RTRIM(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        From NSG_STREET INNER Join NSG_TOWN On NSG_TOWN.TOWN_UID = NSG_STREET.TOWN_UID INNER Join 
        NSG_LOCALITY ON NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_UID = NSG_STREET.LOCALITY_UID INNER JOIN NSG_AUTHORITY ON NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_UID = NSG_STREET.AUTHORITY_UID 
        WHERE CAST(USRN As VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + RTRIM(STREET_DESCRIPTOR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_LOCALITY.LOCALITY_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(NSG_TOWN.TOWN_NAME) + '' + 
        RTrim(NSG_AUTHORITY.AUTHORITY_NAME) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT LIKE '%3%' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

You simply use it everywhere it's referenced, and with everything you compare against (to be safe).

Comment: I ran into this issue today. After a recent security patch was applied, on a script that previously worked fine, I received this error: 
Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in concat operator occurring in SELECT statement. 

Your solution of adding "Collate DATABASE_DEFAULT" immediately after the field name resolved it. No idea where CP850 came from, the tables and DB are all set to CP1.